# Bind a string from Controller to textbox on View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to bind a string which is returned from Controller action to a textbox on View. Any help would be grateful.
Here is my code of Controller:

```
public ActionResult Display(ViewModel.CompanyViewModel entityViewModel)
        {           
            int size=3;

            string password="0123456789";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(size);

            for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(password[rnd.Next(password.Length)]);
            }
            Managers.CompanyManager companyManager = new Managers.CompanyManager();
            entityViewModel.SequentialId = stringBuilder.ToString();
            int isCustomerIDExists = companyManager.isExistsSequentialID(entityViewModel);
            if (isCustomerIDExists > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(password[rnd.Next(password.Length)]);
                }            
            }
            string str = stringBuilder.ToString();

            return Json(new { str = str }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is my code of View-Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function btnNextAvailable_OnClick() {
        $("#nextAvailableButtonClick.val('true')");
        var mode = $.hash.getValue("m");
        var urlInsert = '@Url.Action("Display")';
        $.getJSON(urlInsert, function () {
        });
        document.getElementById("SequentialId").value = '@Url.Action("Display")';
    }
</script>
```

I want to bind string str which is getting returned from Controller action to a textbox 'SequentialID' on view.

here is my code on view:

```
function btnNextAvailable_OnClick() {
        $("#nextAvailableButtonClick.val('true')");
        var mode = $.hash.getValue("m");
        var urlInsert = '@Url.Action("Display")';
        $.get(urlInsert, function () {
        })
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/CompanyController/Display',
            async: false,
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: (function (data) {
                $('#SequentialId').value(data);
            }),
             error: (function () {
                alert("error");
            })
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
function btnNextAvailable_OnClick() {
    $("#nextAvailableButtonClick.val('true')");
    var mode = $.hash.getValue("m");
    var urlInsert = '@Url.Action("Display")';        
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlInsert,
        async: false,
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: (function (data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#SequentialId').val(response.str);
        }),
         error: (function () {
            alert("error");
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Anish, thanks for response. I tried by using Ajax, but each time it will show alert: error on click event of button

Comment: You can check whether it hits the controller actually.. It might be the problem there at code behind.

Comment: Actually it shows the alert: error first and then hits the controller.

Comment: still its blank in textbox 'SequentialId'. Actually tried by  success: (function (data) {
            $('#SequentialId').val(data);

Comment: Can you add debugger; before $('#SequentialId').val(data); and check in console what is coming.

Comment: Hi Anish, there was nothing logged in Chrome->Console. And it seems that controller passes value successfully to browser. When i checked in Developer Tool-> Network->Headers: Request Method is GET. In Network-> Preview :str:"438",Network-> Response: {"str":"438"}. On UI-> in textbox 'SequentilaID':[object Object]

Comment: I have updated the code. Sry for the mislead. Its a Json object getting and we have to retrieve value. hope it will work for u.

Comment: Hi Anish, sorry for troubled you again. I updated Jscript, but still 'SequentialID' textbox is blank. There is an error in Console->"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4." at the same time controller action successfully returns string to browser. {"str":"438"}.

Comment: Thanks Anish for great support.. :-)

Comment: Anish, there was error in parsing data to JSON. So removed code var response = JSON.parse(data);
$('#SequentialId').val(response.str); And directly bind  $('#SequentialId').val(data.str);

Answer (score 1):

You can store string in ViewBag and then append to text box

controller :

```
ViewBag.MyString = "sample text";
```

View:

```
<input type="text" value="@ViewBag.MyString" />
```

For Json result

```
$.get('/Controller/Action', function(data){
   document.getElementById("SequentialId").value = data.str;
});
```

Comment: Hi Irakli, thanks for quick response, But its not working. Still textbox 'SequentialId' is empty.

Comment: Display your Display action needs model as parameter. Try google chrome developer tools network tab to see what is response action response.